# Hash Key value print Issue

Tags: perl, hash

I am not getting count of `$mapA{$Brand_Name}->{Success}`  `$mapA{$Brand_Name}->{Failure}`  please help on this actually i raised this problem in another question i.e closed so i am raising in this.
or any other way to increase the count for particular key.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Text::CSV;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Data::Dumper;
use LWP::Simple;

my $APK_GCM="/root/Basavaraj/GCM/cdr_02-01-2018_StreamzGcm.csv";
my $WEB_GCM="/root/Basavaraj/GCM/cdr_02-01-2018_StreamzWebPushNotification.csv";

my $Yesterday= strftime ("%d-%m-%Y", localtime(time-86400));
my $Current_Date= strftime ("%d-%m-%Y",localtime(time));

print "$Yesterday \n";
print "$Current_Date \n";

open(STDOUT, '>', "/root/Basavaraj/STREAMZ_GCM_APK.txt");
#Creating Class to split the document line by line  by comma ,
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => ',' });

open (my $data, '<:encoding(utf8)', $APK_GCM) or die "Could Not open File '$APK_GCM' $!\n";
open (my $data1,'<:encoding(utf8)', $WEB_GCM) or die "Could Not open File '$WEB_GCM' $!\n";

my %mapA;
my $dummyA =<$data>;
while (my $line = <$data>) {
  if ($csv->parse($line)) {
      my @fields = $csv->fields();
      my $Brand_Name=$fields[2];
      my $Streamz_Sent=$fields[5];
      my $GoogleResA=$fields[5];
      $mapA{$Brand_Name} = {Success =>0,Failure=> 0} unless exists ($mapA{$Brand_Name});
      my $failureA='{error:MismatchSenderId}';
     if ($GoogleResA eq $failureA){
                        $mapA{$Brand_Name}->{Failure}++;
                         print "$Brand_Name:$mapA{$Brand_Name}->{Failure} \n";
                   }else{
                         $mapA{$Brand_Name}->{Success}++; 
                         print "$Brand_Name:$mapA{$Brand_Name}->{Success} \n";
                }

  } else {
      warn "Line could not be parsed: $line\n";
  }
}
#$, = ",";
print " $mapA{$Brand_Name}->{Failure} \n";
my $KeyA;
while (($keyA)=each (%mapA)){
     my $success= $mapA{$Brand_Name}->{Success};
     my $failure=  $mapA{$Brand_Name}->{Failure};
print "$keyA   $mapA{$Brand_Name}->{Failure}++ $mapA{$Brand_Name}->{Success}++ \n";
}
foreach my $name ( keys %mapA) {
    print " $mapA{$Brand_Name}->{Failure} \n";
    print " $mapA{$Brand_Name}->{Success} \n";
    print "$name $mapA{$Brand_Name}->{Success} $mapA{$Brand_Name}->{Failure} \n";
}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to [edit] your question and turn that block of text into actual questions with punctuation. It is very hard to read. It would also be nice to have the code indented properly so we can read it. And you might want to provide example data.

Comment: @simbabque: Alarmingly, the OP is a *Software QA Engineer*

Comment: You're missing `use strict; use warnings;`. Always start with those.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Code looks messy and not clear, but i'm posting here the way to increment the count for this case, hope it will help someway, copy and paste the below program in your machine and try it out(demonstrates how to increment count, very similar to scenario mentioned above)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %results;

%results = ('Brand A' => {'Success' => 0, 'Failure' => 0},
            'Brand B' => {'Success' => 1, 'Failure' => 1});

# add new entry into existing hash 
#
$results{'Brand C'}{'Success'} = 5;
$results{'Brand C'}{'Failure'} = 6;

# increment Success count for specific brand straightaway
$results{'Brand B'}{'Success'}++;
print "Success count for brand B = $results{'Brand B'}{'Success'}\n";

#print out hash
#
# first key for example Brand A
for my $brand (keys %results)
{
    print "Printing brand here: $brand-->";

    # next key for example 'Success' or 'Failure'
    #
    for my $result (keys %{$results{$brand}})
    {
        #increment success or failure count
        $results{$brand}{$result}++;
        print "$result-->$results{$brand}{$result},";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: `!#/usr/bin/perl w`??

Comment: That's not better. You still have what's effectively `! my %results;` with a comment in between, and you shouldn't be using `-w` in the first place (we've had `use warnings;` since 2000), and you're missing `use strict` (available since 1994).

Comment: Thanks for taking out time to correct this, appreciated

Comment: I am undecided on how to vote here. I think you mean well to explain a concept to the OP, and your code is well documented and well structured, but I am missing the `use warnings` pragma, and I am really not sure if this actually answers the question. I don't understand the question, so I prefer to not answer instead of guessing. I will not cast a vote here

Comment: i want to print success count and failure count for each brand but when tried its not printing.You are suggesting to add brands to hash but i am reading line and splitting it based comma separated and i want put unique brand and there success and failure count based on the one more filed

Comment: after using for inside for i am getting success and failure count thanks for ur help

Comment: Understand in this simple way: Brand A(key) contains (Success(key)with value(1) and Failure(key) with value(0), in the first for loop we fetch out the Brand A key first and use it in the inner for loop (see $results{$brand} where brand is actually the Brand A(key)) to further fetch out Success and Failure keys

Comment: For the record , I've added the use warnings;